# How do I pull excerpts from pages?

Tags: functions, loop, the-content, excerpt

So I enabled custom excerpts on my pages with this function.

```
add_action('init', 'page_excerpts');

function page_excerpts() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

However, When I enter a data into the excerpt field I still have the content returning in the loop instead of my newly added excerpt.

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Do I need to do anything else to force the content to be pulled from the excerpt field on pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this:

```
 <?php 
    global $more; 
    $more = false; 
 ?>
 <?php the_content('<span>Continue Reading</span>'); ?>
 <?php $more = true; ?>
```

Comment: That seemed to give me a the full content instead of the excerpt.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't get that completely right.
`<?php global $more; $more = false; ?>
<?php if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) : ?>
<?php the_excerpt(''); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php the_content('<span>Continue Reading</span>'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $more = true; ?>
`

Comment: lol, so if it has the excerpt it pulls the excerpt from the content and if it doesn't have an excerpt it pulls ALL of the content images and all. Still not pulling from the excerpt box.

Comment: Instead of using the_excerpt(), try `echo $post->post_excerpt;`

Comment: One last thing. Could you explain why this worked. It seems almost like a hack to fix something broken with WP. Also, how would you pull off an if excerpt box use. otherwise pull excerpt from content?

Comment: It works because $post->post_excerpt is displaying the raw text directly from the database, whereas the_excerpt() is running the text through filters and other functions that are for some reason stripping it blank for your pages.